# Scale html email to fit within in mobile screen without scroll (android / iOS)

Tags: android, iphone, html-email

I'm trying to build a html email that will scale to fit within a mobile screen without the user need to scroll horizontally. I have tried using...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and setting the body width to 100% - but neither seems to work. Any other suggestions?

Here is my full html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">.ExternalClass .ecxReadMsgBody{width:100%;}   .ExternalClass{width:100%;} body{margin: 0; padding: 0;} </style>

</head>
<body style="background: #dfdfe0; width:100%;">

    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background: #dfdfe0;color: #37383a;margin: 0px;width: 100%;" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="576">

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                        <td colspan="34" style="background-color: red;" bgcolor="red"><img width="522" src="header2.png"></td>
                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> <!-- Start of the email grid -->
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="18" height="10" style="background-color: red; height: 10px;" bgcolor="red"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td> 
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                        <td width="27"></td>
                        <td width="18" style="background-color: red;" bgcolor="red"></td>
                        <td width="9"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks!

EDIT

Please note I also reduced the amount of columns to 5 and I still get the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table width is set in pixels (576px) which is larger than the phone screen size. You could use a [media query (responsive design)](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/) to disable or resize the desktop version to fit a mobile screen, otherwise you need to go with a [fluid design](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3564/applying-fluid-layouts-to-html-email-design/).

Limitations are that media queries don't work in Gmail as you cant inline them. Fluid only really works with single column layouts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

You have specified an absolute width in your table. Change it to 100% width.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to set the inner table width so I can then set the widths for my grid. I did change it to test, and it still didnt work

Comment: Can you try this : <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=medium-dpi">

Comment: Also there are too many individual columns in your table. SO the browser cannot accomodate so many columns without introducing scrollbar horizontally. Reduce the column count or the columns widths.

Comment: Thanks again. medium dpi density did not work. As for the column count, you are incorrect. If you remove the first row with the image, it work work fine. the only email client I have noticed with a column restriction is outlook 2007 (max 62 columns)

Comment: Since you have specified the zoom scale to be 1 and it has too many columns, it could be causing an issue. Can you reduce the columns to accomodate exactly the width of the screen

Comment: Its not too many columns. I just brought the grid down to 5 cols, reduced the colspan of the image to 1, and still the same problem. Its nothing to do with the amount of cols at all. Thanks